# Cacti is not generating the graphics

Tags: apache, graph, snmp, rrdtool, cacti

I have the cacti installed on the ubuntu 18.04 server and it is not generating the graphics. All information is -nan (not a number).

I need to help solve it. Ask for the configuration files that I'm adding to the post.

[image: NAN]

Comment: Look into an xml dump createed with `rrdtool dump filename.rrd >filename.xml` command to see if data is there. Also I see August 2016 on screenshot while rrd files typically store data for 1-2 years (depends on creation options) - maybe you just try to draw too old data which are no longer in rrd file?

Comment: Sorry, i have uploaded the wrong screeshot. Here is the correct one.

Comment: Is snmpd running on your host? Is it configured to accept and reply to snmp queries from cacti's ip? No firewall issues? Can you get traffic counters from cli (for example `snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost ifHCInOctets`)

Comment: Here is the xml generated by rdtool
http://www.l9web.com.br/_PUB/foruns/localhost_traffic_in_6.xml

Comment: Since all values in all rra in xml dump are NaN  values were never successfully added to rrd file. There is nothing to draw. So your problem is that poller doesn't get  data. last update in rrd file is 2018-12-28 10:20:02 - it means poller writes undefined values into rrd. Try to debug poller.

Comment: Very likely your problem is related to php-snmp bug - google  for `POLLER: Poller[Main Poller] ASSERT: '1219959<0:0:02:06.13' failed. Recaching host '127.0.0.1'` string or look at github issues and solutions here: https://github.com/Cacti/cacti/issues/1634 , https://github.com/Cacti/cacti/issues/1663

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts and changes in the php files I decided to download the alpha4 version 1.2.0 from Cacti.

Cacti 1.1.38 is incompatible with php 7.2.

Follow the link for version 1.2 beta4: https://github.com/Cacti/cacti/archive/develop.zip

Answer (score 0):

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost ifHCInOctets

root@fw:/usr/share/cacti/site/rra# snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost ifHCInOctets
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.1 = Counter64: 2577976
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.2 = Counter64: 19466
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.3 = Counter64: 3705562
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.4 = Counter64: 24305164
```